# Dates in sqlite3 database return as nil in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I've been trying to figure how to craft this question so Google would give me a relevant result because it has to be something stupidly simple I'm missing. I created a simple one table Rails app using the command:

```
rails g scaffold sick name:text sick_day:date shift:text hours:decimal
```

I ran `rake db:migrate` and it worked just fine. I then used SQLite Manager in Firefox to import the data. Here is the first three lines of the CSV file:

```
name,sick_day,shift,hours,created_at,updated_at
"Doe, Jane",3/3/2015,C,24,4/12/16,4/12/16
"Smith, John",1/20/2015,C,4,4/12/16,4/12/16
"Smith, John",3/27/2015,C,24,4/12/16,4/12/16
```

I used Excel to insert the created_at and updated_at dates because they are not_null fields. It works great. I can browse the DB with SQLite Manager and see everything:

[image: data sample]

But when I query the DB using the rails console I get:

```
Sick Load (3.2ms)  SELECT  "sicks".* FROM "sicks" LIMIT 3
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
#<Sick name: "Doe, Jane", sick_day: "2015-03-03 00:00:00", shift: "C", hours: 24.0, created_at: "2004-12-16 00:00:00", updated_at: "2004-12-16 00:00:00">, 
#<Sick name: "Smith, John", sick_day: nil, shift: "C", hours: 4.0, created_at: "2004-12-16 00:00:00", updated_at: "2004-12-16 00:00:00">, 
#<Sick name: ""Smith, John", sick_day: nil, shift: "C", hours: 24.0, created_at: "2004-12-16 00:00:00", updated_at: "2004-12-16 00:00:00">]>
```

Any idea why my dates are nil? They are definitely in the DB, and I don't understand why it would understand some dates and not others? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it but it still seems weird that it didn't work. I tried changing the CSV file to:

```
name,sick_day,shift,hours,created_at,updated_at
"Doe, Jane",3/3/15,C,24,4/12/16,4/12/16
"Smith, John",1/20/15,C,4,4/12/16,4/12/16
"Smith, John",3/27/15,C,24,4/12/16,4/12/16
```

and re-import it, but it still didn't work. I then used Excel to change the format and convert it to an actual text column in the format:

```
name,sick_day,shift,hours,created_at,updated_at
"Doe, Jane",2015/3/3,C,24,4/12/16,4/12/16
"Smith, John",2015/1/20,C,4,4/12/16,4/12/16
"Smith, John",2015/3/27,C,24,4/12/16,4/12/16
```

and re-imported that. Now Rails is happy. ???

Comment: SQLite doesn't have any date or time types so they're just strings inside the database (https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). You're using a weird format (i.e. anything other than ISO8601) so there is lots of room for confusion when the date strings get parsed. If you use the One True Date Format (i.e. ISO8601's YYYY/MM/DD) then there is no ambiguity or confusion and SQLite's date functions will even work properly on the strings.

Comment: I get that, thus my answer. But even when all three columns were in the mm/dd/yy format two columns worked and one didn't. I prefer YYYY/MM/DD but stupid Excel is stupid. LOL

Comment: The date format is ambiguous so AR is left to guess what the strings mean, sometimes it guesses wrong. More or less. Look at what Rails thinks of those `created_at` values and you'll see more confusion. Switching all dates and times to ISO8601 during the export or import process is really the only sensible thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's a mismatch in the format between your `sick_day` column and your `created_at` and `updated_at` columns. Try changing the year format in `sick_day` to two-digit years and see if that works.

Also, it's generally preferable to allow Rails to set the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps for you. You could accomplish this by writing an importer script and running it with `rails runner` (for example) but that's outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: You missed the part where I tried it using the exact same format and it didn't work. And the `created_at/updated_at` part was just because I had an existing CSV file being imported into SQLite Manager and Rails had already made those columns not_null so I needed something to fill those spots. I don't care about those columns at all. My point being that I created two columns in the text file using `mm/dd/yy` and the existing column that was in the same format but it didn't work. I then changed it to `mm/dd/yyy`, with same results, and finally `yyyy/mm/dd` to get it to work.

Comment: Sorry, I mean you missed that in my answer to myself below.